# IntelliJ increase Scalatest Heap space

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jvm, heap-memory, scalatest

I'm using IntelliJ to run Scalatest tests. Problem I'm having is the tests are running out of Heap space (likely because my tests are using Selenium and starting up jettys to hit my Api).

I know how to increase my Heap space in IntelliJ but after increasing the space the tests still run out of Heap.

Is there a different place to increase Heap space for tests rather than the usual IntelliJ info.plist (oh btw I'm on Mac)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

go to `Edit Configurations`:

[image]

Choose the test on the left, and tweak its `VM options`:

[image]

---

In case you are using a ScalaTest [ant task](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_ant_task), there is a `jvmarg` that you can set:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"/>
```

Comment: WEIRD. I can't copy the text in your image. I'LL NEVER FIGURE THIS OUT NOW.

Answer (score 2):

As you rightly observed, it is not IDEA's heap size that needs to be increased but rather that of the ScalaTest *run configuration* accessible from the ***Run > Edit Configurations...*** dialog. There, you should be able to set the ***VM Options*** for the tests you are trying to run.